# ¿Como lanzar actividad en blanco al presionar boton SearchView?

Tags: php, java, android, mysql, android-studio

estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](http://androidcss.com/android/android-search-view-php-mysql/) para crear un SearchView en android studio con php y mysql todo funciona bien el unico problema es que los resultados de la busqueda se muestran en un Recyclerview que esta en el layout principal de la app o sea el activity_main donde yo ya tengo otras cosas para mi app, quisiera saber como podria mostrar los resultados en un layout en blanco al momento de hacer la busqueda sin tener que salir de la actividad principal, espero su consejo gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ocupas dividir la pantalla amigo

Aquí aplicarías definir "pesos" con la propiedad layout_weight en tu vista, suponiendo el siguiente ejemplo, en el cual necesitamos que nuestra vista de abajo siempre ocupe un 50% de la pantalla y este posicionado en la parte inferior, pero también necesitamos agregar otras 2 vistas, las cuales una ocupe el 30% de la pantalla y la segunda el 20%.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tomamos en cuenta el total de la pantalla como el 1 , asignamos un valor de .50 para que siempre ocupe el 50% de la pantalla nuestra vista :

```
   <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

y asi con las demás vistas, una ocupara el 30% (asignamos .30) y la otra el 20% (asignamos .20):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:text="Vista 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:text="Vista 2" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Podemos asegurar que las vistas tendran el porcentaje especificado en la pantalla y tu decides donde obtener el resultado.

Espero mi palomita amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

En el layout principal creas 2 layouts y en el que quede en la parte inferior agregas el recyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Layout Superior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="116dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_01">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="142dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="142dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Resultados" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

En este caso el tamaño (`android:layout_height="200dp"`) es de 200 dp, pero puede ser el que quieras o si quieres que ocupen mitad de pantalla agrega `android:layout_weight=".5"`